# IE adding extra HTML tags while rendering

Tags: html, internet-explorer, render

I have following HTML markup as an input to be pasted onto IE browser in place of selected content on the browser:

```
<span id='fs_892_3006_0' class='ParaMarked' FactType='NonNumeric' onclick='OnSpanClick("fs_892_3006_0", event)' IsFactMarked='true'>
    <fact id='892_3006_0' keyword=''>
        <P style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt; line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt;">
            <SPAN style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">THIS IS A TEST CONTENT 1</SPAN>
        </P>
    </fact>
</span>
```

However, when the HTML is rendered, IE adds extra tags surrounding this HTML as shown below:

```
<p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt; line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt;">
   <span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">
        <span id="fs_892_3006_0" class="ParaMarked" onclick='OnSpanClick("fs_892_3006_0", event)' IsFactMarked="true" FactType="NonNumeric">
          <fact id="892_3006_0" keyword="">
</p><p style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10pt; line-height: 115%; font-size: 11pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">THIS IS A TEST CONTENT 1</span></p></fact></span></span>
```

I have tried below techniques to paste HTML onto browser, but gives same result: 
Note: "markedText" is the javascript variable which contains the HTML input as mentioned above 
 1. pasteHTML(markedText) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536656(v=vs.85).aspx 
 2. Rangy library : 
            var sel = rangy.getSelection();
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var node = range.createContextualFragment(markedText);
            range.insertNode(node);

Any pointers on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The nesting seems to be wrong: <span><fact><p><span></span></p></span></fact>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Somehow, the input code box above missed </span> tag. Updated the input above. Still facing the issue....

Comment: Try replacing the <p> element with inline element, say, another <span>. Make it block-level using CSS. Maybe IE or your wysiwig (if any) tries to make inline elems not contain blocks. Also, what is <fact>? Can't find it in google.

Comment: <fact> is a custom tag required for further processing of html documents.


The <p> element is from an input file taken from anonymous source. I do not have control on changing this content. The only manipulation I do here is, add the custom <span> and <fact> tags around the input HTML and paste it on browser. 
Take it as this way:
1. You get selected input HTML from browser.
2. Add <span...><fact...>Input HTML </fact></span>
3. Paste html output from point 2 in place of selected HTML of point 1.

Comment: Ok then, if you have control over the span wrapper, try replacing it with <div>, maybe it will help.

Comment: Also, try what will happen if you do not add any wrappers — just the selected text. Will IE add extra markup in such case?

Comment: Apologies for delayed response.
Tried <div> instead of <span> and also, tested after removing the wrappers.. same result! Extra tags were added.

Answer (score 0):

A p inside a span will probably not work, as it's a block level element inside an inline element.

Some browsers will "fix" the issue by wrapping the inline elements in a block level element (default a 'p') and continue with the rest of the markup.

Comment: Yeah. This is understandable if only extra <p> is added without any inline styling. However, in above case, both <p> and <span> were added with the same styling (i.e. exact copy) of html content. Any reason for this?